# How to deal with large merModLmerTest

Tags: r, lme4, large-data-volumes

I try to use R on my laptop to run the HLM regression of a large dataset of about 2GB(500,000 lines), and the format of this dataset is spss(.sav).Sorry I could not share the data, as required by my professor, but I would try my best to provide as many details as possible. Here is some codes of mine.

```
data<- spss.get("Stanford Dataset .sav")
result1 <- lmer(SCIENCE ~ GDP + Individualism+ Gender+ Gender*GDP+
              Individualism*Gender + (1+Gender|Country/School),data = data)
summary(result1)
```

And the problem is, it takes me about 5 minutes to run a regression and print the `summary`. Is there any faster way to deal with this large memory model?

Actually I have tried some of the following methods:

1) use `data.table` in `data.table` package. `data <- data.table(data)`  before run the regression . Howevern I wait for the results with more mins than before.

2) use `as.big.matrix` in package  `bigmemory`, and it shows the error:

> Error in list2env(data) : first argument must be a named list

Seems that the matrix is not working in the function `lmer`.

So I am really lack of thoughts now, any relative idea would be helpful.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe try running the model on a small sample of your data and then passing the parameters to the full model to get it started. But I don't think 5 minutes is unexpected for a big dataset and reasonably complex model like this, and things like `data.table` probably won't help as I think most of the slowness comes from `lmer` building and then operating on model matrices.

Comment: Thx @Marius, `data.table` takes me 1 more min to print out the result LOL. And  could you be more detailed on running a sample model first and then passing the parameters to the full model? I just do know how this would shorten the time I might use on `lmer` or `glmer`